# Running a global node module binary from crontab

Tags: node.js, bash, cron, node-modules

I'm trying to run a node module (`npm install -g lungo-cli`) from within my `crontab`.

What I've tried is to call the node binary from crontab:

```
* * * * * lungo
```

No luck.

Then I tried with:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/lungo
```

Again, no luck.

So finally I did what I thought it was a workaround, calling the node module directly from a javascript file using shelljs.

*Javascript:*

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
shell.exec('lungo')
```

I even tried running it locally!

```
const lungo = require('lungo-cli/bin/lungo')
const shell = require('shelljs')

const shell.exec('lungo')
```

*Crontab:*

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/node $HOME/scripts/lungo.js
```

And it's the same, it's not working, it seems like `crontab` is running in a completely different environment than my `zsh` shell and can't find any binaries other than the OSX specific ones like `cat`, `rm`, `cd` and so on.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.14.1 (Mojave) and `zsh` as my shell.

How could I accomplish this? I want to be able to call my node cli programs with crontab.

Comment: Is it working in a script file? Make it work in a script, add whatever needed to the script, export variables, add the `#!/bin/bash` whatever needed. Then point the crontab to the script file. It will be much easier to debug.

Comment: I've also tried writing a script file with the shebang and all stuff, it's not working either, I outputted an `echo` to a log file and that does work, however, the node cli binary gets lost and never executes.

Comment: Did you try other node module? It could be an issue with the lungo app itself, not the lungo-cli. Maybe the lungo-cli expect some extra enviromet variables to exist that are not available in crontab context. Anyway it looks like a very basic package, try to execute the command itself without the node package. look here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/lungo-cli/blob/master/api.js#L15

Comment: It works outside crontab, even using shelljs, the problem is the crontab enviroment not reading the global node bin.

Comment: Just made it run with success with this crontab: `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lungo-cli./cli.js` although I want to execute the binary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Oh-my-zsh in my macbook so I've tried many things to get the crontab task runs but finally, my solution was prepending the .zshrc before the command to run.

```
*/30 * * * * . $HOME/.zshrc; node  /path/for/my_script.js
```

This task runs every 30 minutes and uses .zshrc profile to execute my node command. Don't forget to use the dot before the $HOME var.

By the way, you can run any command attached to your zsh environment.